# Angularjs Unexpected token JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonparser

I have a problem with angularjs and JSON.

This is my code.

list_user.jsp (this is the page where I print the table)

```
<tr ng-repeat="per in persons">
  <td>{{ per.user }}</td>
  <td>{{ per.password }}</td>
  <td>{{ per.profile }}</td>
</tr>
```

controller.js

```
 $http({
      method : 'POST',
      url : 'views/user/user.json'
    }).success(function(data){
      $scope.persons = data;
    });
```

user.json

```
 [
        {
            "user": "Quarterback",
            "password": 5,
            "profile": "ppp"        
        },
        {
            "user": "Wide Receiver",
            "password": 89,
            "profile": "oooo"
        }
    ]
```

This way the table is generated correctly, but the json is fixed. 
Now I'll paste the code with which I want to print the data by taking them from a query

controller.js

```
 $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'views/user/user.jsp'
    }).success(function(data){

        /*
        var jsonStr="your json string";
        var json=JSON.stringify(data);
        json=JSON.parse(json)
        console.log(json);
        */
        console.log(data);
        $scope.persons = data;
    });
```

The code between / * .. * / left them to show that I also tried that road without success.

user.jsp

```
JSONArray jdata = new JSONArray(); 
UserRest as = new UserRest();
jdata = as.getAll();
logger.info("jdata in user.jsp "+jdata);
```

UserRest.class (just paste the code where I create the JSON)

```
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
      User ut = (User) iter.next();
      JSONObject jtemp = new JSONObject();
      jtemp.put("user", ut.getUserName());
      jtemp.put("password", ut.getPassword());
      jtemp.put("profilo", ut.getProfilo());
      jarray.put(jtemp);
    }
    return  jarray;
```

the result of logger.info("jdata in user.jsp "+jdata) in user.jsp

```
jdata in user.jsp [{"user":"aaaaaaa","password":"1111111","profile":"0"},{"user":"bbbbbbbb","password":"222222222","profile":"1"}]
```

As you can see the json looks the same, but when in the browser I call the list_user.jsp page in the console the value "data" in controller.js returns me

```
 <? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
```

I also tried with JSON.parse or JSON.stringify but it does not work.
I also added "track by $ index" here:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "for people track by $ index">
```

in list_user.jsp but it does not work.

Please help me because I do not know how to do it anymore.

Comment: How do you return `jdata` from user.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your problem appears to be that you should call a SERVICE, not a jsp.

A JSP builds a new web page for you and so it will put that:

```
< ? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"? >
```

Try doing, instead a jsp, a servlet (or use JAX-RS, as you prefer) and putting you logic inside the 'doGet' method (again, or use JAX-RS).

Do a simple thing, like

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.getWriter().append(your working JSON properly hardcoded);
}
```

This way should work. Then put your service logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much **@inigoD**, I solved my problem.
Following the new code.

controller.js (UserRest is the servlet)

```
$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'UserRest'
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.persons = data;
    });
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>UserRest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>"path application".UserRest</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/UserRest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

UserRest.class

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try
        {
            JSONArray jdata = new JSONArray();
            jdata = getAll();

            logger.info("prima del response "+jdata);

            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(jdata.toString());

        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The function getAll() Is the same as I had pasted on, which contained this code.

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      User ut = (User) iter.next();
      JSONObject jtemp = new JSONObject();
      jtemp.put("user", ut.getUserName());
      jtemp.put("password", ut.getPassword());
      jtemp.put("profilo", ut.getProfilo());
      jarray.put(jtemp);
    }
    return  jarray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem with servlet, but I would like call a REST api.
I prefer don't use the servlet.
I change my code.

controller.js

```
angular.module('inspinia')
.controller("DataTable",['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/api/utenti' 
    }).success(function(data){
        $scope.persons = data;
    });
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.xxx.yyy.userInterface.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

UtentiController.class

```
@Path("/utenti")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class UtentiController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JSONArray getAll() {
       /* call the interface that return a json */

       return jarray;
    }
}
```

the error in the console is:

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /api/utenti/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

Thanks for your help